# Can Kubenetes pod preemption happens between multi schedulers?

Tags: kubernetes, preemption, kubernetes-pod

From [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/) I know that a Pod must be scheduled by one scheduler. Such as scheduler `A` schedule pod `a` and scheduler `B` schedule pod `b`.

The question is that:  can `a` preempt `b` if `b` is already running? Which scheduler will do this operation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware Pods are not evicted by schedulers at all. It's kubelets job to nuke pod if it ie. no longer fits in the node or something similar. You do have a [Descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/descheduler) if you want that, but that is a completely different piece of the puzzle. Your own custom scheduler could also implement descheduler logic of some kind if you want to merge this, but then you'd need to make sure on your own that descheduling logic does not collide within your multiple deschedulers.

To stress again, this is not a part of the cluster builds by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's 
very inspiring. I found the preemption is [described](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/) as `When a Pod cannot be scheduled, the scheduler tries to preempt (evict) lower priority Pods to make scheduling of the pending Pod possible`. And then the schedulers should follow the same priority rules? If a scheduler owner forgot it, pods will be scheduled in a loop?

Comment: Indeed, but for that, preemption needs to be enabled in the first place, and priorities defined. I think there will be no reason not to evict pods scheduled by other schedulers if they have lower priority defined. They would then get rescheduled by their original scheduler in a new place.